# Is it possible Horizontal calenderview scrolling in android?

Tags: android, layout, calendarview

from the above code Calendar is diplayed but it is scrolling vertically not horizontally.

please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Try searching git hub before you ask and please follow the stackoverflow standards for asking a question.
For a fully feldged calender that scrolls horizonatlly u can use this lib: [MaterialCalenderView](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)